# What is the English word for a place where elders congregate in the morning?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, history

I know I learned this word in high school during one of Mr. Byrd's history classes. It has been over a decade since then and now I can't recall what it was.

I distinctly remember that we were learning about the historical governing practices of villages and small communities. There was a name for the informal morning congregation that was common among elders, generals and community leaders. We learned that people of influence would often meet in the morning to discuss current events and politics. These meetings would at times undermine the official means of governance within the community. I remember this clearly because there was a cafe in our small town where this exact thing was still occurring but I can't for the life of me remember what it was called.

Does this sound familiar to anyone else? I tried googling it but there are simply to many websites of young people complaining about old people crowding out McDonalds to find anything useful. Thanks in advance for your help

*edit This is a word for the place but only because the place is used for the "for the informal morning congregation".

Comment: Since you specifically mention generals, it sounds as though you are looking for something very specific to a particular culture... so where and when are you talking about?

Comment: Title says "word for a place", body says "name for the informal morning congregation". Is this a word for *both* the place *and* the meeting?

Comment: Is this specific to American villages?

Comment: This is a word for the place but only because the place is used for the "for the informal morning congregation"

Comment: @KennethMoore Perfect. Can you edit to clarify that in the question.

Comment: Kaffeeklatsch is the closest I can think of but is 1) German and 2) more social and gossipy rather than back room cryptigovernment machinations. Was this a single word or a phrase, any pronunciation or other features you can remember? Is it a word that might show up in the news? Or is it vulgar or less than formal?

Comment: assembly, assemblage, agora (Greek),...

Comment: What history class was Mrs Byrd teaching? What time period was she talking about? In what part of the world is your small town located? The USA? New England? England. Ireland? Australia?

Comment: In much of Canada it's called Tim Hortons.  In Renaissance Italian towns there is almost always a "loggia" across the main piazza from the town hall and I suspect it served the same purpose when built.

Comment: Mr. Byrd taught US Government and Civics in a rural mid-American high-school.

Comment: For some reason I believe the word may have started with "C" and may have ended in "post"

Comment: Requests to help you remember something you’ve forgotten are off topic. This is what we call a "guessing game" question. They're not a good fit for the site – or, to my knowledge, any SE site. See: [Let’s Play The Guessing Game – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)

Comment: This is true. I sincerely apologize I will edit my question to be more valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a "moot"? Or is that word older than what you had in mind?

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moot):

> a deliberative assembly primarily for the administration of justice
>   especially : one held by the freemen of an Anglo-Saxon community

Answer (score 0):

Could you be thinking of a *common* or *commons*?

> common
>
> noun
>
> ...
>
> 5 :a piece of land subject to common use: such as
>
> a :undivided land used especially for pasture
>
> b :a public open area in a municipality
>
> A food and jazz festival will be held at the town common.

Source: [Merriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commons)

> noun
>
> ...
>
> 16. Often, commons. Chiefly New England. a tract of land owned or used jointly by the residents of a community, usually a central square or park in a city or town.
> 17. commons. (used with a singular verb) a large dining room, especially at a university or college.

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/commons?s=t)

Answer (score -1):

Given your comment about their word beginning with "c" and ending with "post", your teacher may have made a historical reference to the ***Curia Hostilia***:

> The ***Curia Hostilia*** was one of the original senate houses or "curia" of the Roman Republic. It is believed to have begun as a temple where the warring tribes laid down their arms during the reign of Romulus (r. c. 771–717 BC). During the early monarchy, the temple was used by senators acting as council to the king.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curia_Hostilia)</sub>